# How to code this in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I'm trying to code in Z3 a very simple problem but I got confuse and I don't know how to solve it properly.

So I have an Array with these elements (Python syntax style code):

```
array = [0, -1, 1, 8, 43]
```

And I have an access to this array using an index:

```
x = array[index]
```

And finally I want to ask z3 what index I need to use to get the element 8, in my example the solution is `index = 3` (starting at 0).

I am trying to code this problem in Z3, I wrote the next lines:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const index Int)

(assert (= x
           (ite (= index 0)
                0
           (ite (= index 1)
                -1
           (ite (= index 2)
                1
           (ite (= index 3)
                8
           (ite (= index 4)
                43
           999999)))))))
(assert (= x 8))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

And it is working, I had this solution:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun index () Int
    3)
  (define-fun x () Int
    8)
)
```

But I don't like the last else, the 999999. I needed to use a magic number to know when the value is not found. I tried to see if there is a "it" construction without the else, or a NULL/None/UNSAT or any special value to don't have this problem.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about the *"correct"* way to solve this problem, since one should probably define *"correct"* in the first place.

However, there are many ways in which you can encode it as an *smt2* formula.

---

**Example 0.**

By simply forcing *index* to fall within the domain *[0, 4]*, you can get the *ite* do what you want it to do without the need for any *magic number*.

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const index Int)

(assert (= x
           (ite (= index 0)
                0
           (ite (= index 1)
                -1
           (ite (= index 2)
                1
           (ite (= index 3)
                8
           43))))))

(assert (and (<= 0 index) (<= index 4)))

(assert (= x 8))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

which returns you the desired model:

```
~$ z3 example_00.smt2 
sat
(model 
  (define-fun index () Int
    3)
  (define-fun x () Int
    8)
)
```

---

**Example 1.**

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const index Int)

(assert (ite (= index 0) (= x 0) true))
(assert (ite (= index 1) (= x (- 1)) true))
(assert (ite (= index 2) (= x 1) true))
(assert (ite (= index 3) (= x 8) true))
(assert (ite (= index 4) (= x 43) true))

(assert (and (<= 0 index) (<= index 4)))

(assert (= x 8))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

which returns you the desired model:

```
~$ z3 example_01.smt2 
sat
(model 
  (define-fun index () Int
    3)
  (define-fun x () Int
    8)
)
```

---

**Example 2.**

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const index Int)

(assert (or (not (= index 0)) (= x 0)))      ;; (= index 0) -> (= x 0)
(assert (or (not (= index 1)) (= x (- 1))))
(assert (or (not (= index 2)) (= x 1)))
(assert (or (not (= index 3)) (= x 8)))
(assert (or (not (= index 4)) (= x 43)))

(assert (and (<= 0 index) (<= index 4)))

(assert (= x 8))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

which returns you the desired model:

```
~$ z3 example_02.smt2 
sat
(model 
  (define-fun index () Int
    3)
  (define-fun x () Int
    8)
)
```

---

**Example 3.**

Using the *Theory of Arrays*

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun index () Int)
(declare-const ar (Array Int Int))

  ; array's locations initialization
(assert (= (store ar 0 0)     ar))
(assert (= (store ar 1 (- 1)) ar))
(assert (= (store ar 2 1)     ar))
(assert (= (store ar 3 8)     ar))
(assert (= (store ar 4 43)    ar))

  ; x = ar[index]
(assert (= (select ar index) x))

  ; bound index to fall within specified locations
(assert (and (<= 0 index) (<= index 4)))

  ; x = 8
(assert (= x 8))

  ; check
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

which returns you the desired model:

```
~$ z3 example_03.smt2
sat
(model 
  (define-fun x () Int
    8)
  (define-fun ar () (Array Int Int)
    (_ as-array k!0))
  (define-fun index () Int
    3)
  (define-fun k!0 ((x!0 Int)) Int
    (ite (= x!0 2) 1
    (ite (= x!0 3) 8
    (ite (= x!0 1) (- 1)
    (ite (= x!0 0) 0
    (ite (= x!0 4) 43
      5))))))
)
```

---

Other examples are possible.

Ideally one would pick the encoding for which *z3* has the best performance in solving your formula. On this regard I can not help you, since I typically deal with *other SMT solvers*.

In general, using more complex theories (e.g. *Theory of Arrays*) results in the run-time executing more expensive routines so one could think that it's best to avoid it. However, I would say that in my experience this is not a general *rule of thumb*, since even slight variations  of the encoding can result in significant performance differences and *very poor* or *naive* encodings can perform pretty bad. Therefore, it's always best to perform extensive *bench-marking* on various candidate encodings.